# Invoking method from app.Query in xamarin.uitest returns error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

The goal is to check whether element has focus. I stumbled upon [this solution](https://xamarinhelp.com/get-element-properties-uitest-xamarin/).
But the result is error.
Here is similar code to what I'm doing:

```
app.Query(x => x.Marked("AutomationId").Child(2).Invoke("IsFocused"))[0]
```

output in REPL window is this:

```
{
    error => [

    ],
    receiverClass => [

    ],
    receiverString => [

    ],
    methodName => [

    ]
}
```

Target element is Xamarin.Forms.Entry, so it has property `IsFocused`. `Android.Views.View` also contains property `IsFocused`. I tried to change name "IsFocused" to "getIsFocused", "get_IsFocused" and "GetIsFocused", but the result is the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was wrong.

- Firstly, `IsFocused` is property (not a method), so you need to use method `Property` instead of `Invoke`.
- Secondly, after getting property you need to apply in the same query `Value<>` method.
- Thirdly, it's `Focused` instead of `IsFocused`, even though property's name in both Xamarin and Android is `IsFocused`.

So in this case code would look like this:

```
app.Query(x => x.Marked("AutomationId").Child(2).Property("Focused").Value<bool>())[0]
```